# Displaying Name instead of reference ID in gridview

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have 4 tables tblEmployee,tblDepartment.tblCompany,tblNationality , first table is parent table with reference ID's to all three tables. follwoing is my code which fetches employee data details

```
public JsonResult EmployeeRequests()
{
    List<EmployeeRequests> CO = new List<EmployeeRequests>();
    using (EmployeeContext dc = new EmployeeContext())
    {
        //var cust = dc.Customers.OrderBy(a => a.ContactName).ToList();
        dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

       var cust = dc.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.EmpName).ToList();
          foreach (var i in cust)
        {
            var requests = dc.Requests.Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(i.EmployeeID)).OrderBy(a => a.RequestDate).ToList();
            CO.Add(new EmployeeRequests
            {
                Employee = i,
                Requests = requests
            });
        }        

    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = CO, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

i am using DataViewController.js this is a script file (AngularJS)

```
 angular.module('MyApp')  //extending angular module from first part
.controller('DataViewController', function ($scope, RequestService) { //explained about controller in Part2
    $scope.Requests = [];


    RequestService.GetRequests().then(function (d) {
        $scope.Requests = d.data
    });
})

.factory('RequestService', function ($http) { //explained about factory in Part2
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetRequests = function () {
        return $http.get('/Data/EmployeeRequests');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

DataView.cshtml is as follows in the below view i tried to display O.Company.CompName , O.Department.DeptName , O.Natioality.NatName , but it displays nothing .

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="O in Requests" >           
            <tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">             

                <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.EmployeeID}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.EmpName}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.IqamaNo}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.CompanyID}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.DepartmentID}}</td>
                <td>{{O.Employee.NationalityID}}</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you check value for `d` and `d.data`?

Comment: what's in the `d.data`

Comment: can you also check value for `CO`?

Comment: Are u sure your angular js file is working?